# Displaying image loading process as % on page load

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make loading screen. So i use jQuery for that.

```
<div class="loading">
    <p class="percentage"></p>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var percentage = $(".loading .percentage")
        imgs = $("img"),
        imgPercentage = (100 / imgs.length),
        curPercentage = 0;
    imgs.on("load",function(){
        curPercentage += imgPercentage;
        percentage.text(Math.round(curPercentage) + '%');
    });
});
```

So as you see I'm using `img` and trying to display img's load percentage 'till 100%. But there is a problem. Because it doesn't update it 'till 100%, it just stopping at **67%**.

Comment: Try setting the text `percentage.text(Math.round(curPercentage) + '%');` instead of appending it

Comment: thank you, it solved the updating issue but, it doesn't go till 100% stopping for example 67%.  how can I make it go till 100%. @Claudio

Answer (score 0):

```
function loader(imagearray) {
        var increment = Math.floor(100 / imagearray.length);
        $(imagearray).each(function() {
            $('<img>').attr("src", this).load(function() {
                $('.progress-bar').animate({
                    width: "+=" + increment + "%"
                }, 100);
            });
        });
        calcPercent = setInterval(function() {
            $percent.text(Math.floor(($progress.width() / $('.loader').width()) * 100) + '%');

        });
    }
```